# Why there is no null pointer exception?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

In the documentation code of java **"out"** is an object of PrintStream class which is initialized in the System class of package lang.This object **"out"** is initialized to null.So why does'nt the code throws a null pointer exception whenever the line

*System.out.println(...); is used*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406703/whats-the-meaning-of-system-out-println-in-java

Comment: because the `JVM` initializes `out` with `null`, and afterwards sets it to the default `PrintStream` provided

Comment: ***native*** is the trick here!

Comment: [just going to throw this in, as i feel this should be the actual duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743760/system-out-is-declared-as-static-final-and-initialized-with-null)

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy - Yup :)  Have replaced the dupe link.

Answer (score 3):

It is the field declaration.

Look at the `initializeSystemClass()` static method :

```
setOut0(newPrintStream(fdOut, props.getProperty("sun.stdout.encoding")))
```

The `out` is well initialized at a time  by the VM.

The method is commented with this :

```
/**
 * Initialize the system class.  Called after thread initialization.
 */
```

Answer (score -1):

The `.out` variable is a static variable of `System`. It's the default outputStream and not null.

Java Documentation: This stream is already open and ready to accept output data.

Comment: This is wrong. It is first initialized to null, then later to the correct `PrintStream`.

Comment: `out` is actually a `final static` variable and will be initialized later on [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743760/system-out-is-declared-as-static-final-and-initialized-with-null)

Comment: It is a final static variable that is initialised to null.

Comment: Okay you are right. Sorry for the wrong information.